# Increase font for pdf using Inkscape

Tags: pdf, graphics, fonts, inkscape

I use to produce pdf graphs with R then I like to modify them using inkscape.
Yet when I increase font, letter size increase but letter spacing don't as you can see in example.[image]

[image]

I have the same problem when I do the same with pdf from latex.
Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have broken the text into individual letters, and are applying the new font size to those, rather than to the entire word? You may need to recreate the Xlabel text/group the letters back together.

Comment: No I checked that is not the problem. Does any one has the same problem or this is only related to my inkscape version ?

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an answer for exactly the same question [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=17973), I will duplicate it:

You should select the text you want to resize and then remove manual kerning either before or after the resizing. This can be done by clicking *Text -> Remove Manual Kerns*.